# How many options do we have to divide $k$ balls to $n$ cells (2 conditions)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many options do we have to divide $k$ balls to $n$ cells if $k\geq n$ and:

**CONDITION 1:** Every cell will have at least one ball.

**CONDITION 2:** different $k$ balls, different $n$ cells, and there is significance to how we sort the balls in the cells.

Well, I divided the solution to two parts:

**PART 1:** if $k = n$, then we have $k!$ options.

**PART 2:** if $k > n$, then we put one ball to every cell, for that we have $k!$ options, and then we have left $k-n$ balls to divide to $n$ cells. which is $(k-n)^n$ options.

Then we sum it all: $k! + k!(k-n)^n$ options.

What do you guys think?

Btw, there's a **BONUS** question to that, what will be your answer if we change from different $n$ cells to, these $n$  cells are now identical.

Well, I believe it will be $\frac{k!}{k}$ for $k = n$, and will be $\frac {k! + k!(k-n)^n}{k}$ for $k > n$.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have a look here http://www.careerbless.com/aptitude/qa/permutations_combinations_imp7.php

Comment: By "different $k$ balls, different $n$ cells", do you mean that each cell contains a different number of balls ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Of curse not. You have k different balls to distribute over n different cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial thing is that order in the cells matters.

There are $k!$ ways to line up the balls. Now we want to insert separators into $n-1$ of the $k-1$ gaps between balls. This can be done in $\binom{k-1}{n-1}$ ways, for a total of $k!\binom{k-1}{n-1}$.

We leave it to you to collect the bonus. The answer to the first part will be useful.

Comment: I will review tomorrow a little bit more on the material before I accept your answer. I'm very confused with order matters/not and with identical and different cells etc. I will come back with questions if I don't understand. got like 7 courses apart from discrete :(

Comment: Overloaded! Yes, do ask questions. This question has an unusual character, since order in the cells matters. In most ball and urn counting problems you will meet, it doesn't.

Comment: I still didn't get it 100%, but kinda got it. I'll ask my teacher to explain me further. About the Bonus, it is your answer and I need to divide it by (n-1)!  ?

Comment: I think it is by $n!$.

Comment: Well, so here's the answer: when the cells are different. the answer would be $C(n,k) * n! * (n-k)^n$ and when cells are the same  $C(n,k)  * (n-k)^n$. and you ask why? Because $C(n,k)$ = Every cell will have 1 balls. $n!$ Because we have $n$ different cells.  and $(n-k)^n$ because we have $n-k$ balls left to spread into $n$ cells. Thus, $C(n,k) * n! * (n-k)^n$ is the correct answer to my question. Maybe yours too, but mine is  more comprehensive. What do you think @Andre?

Comment: My analysis is different. Perhaps we don't quite have the same interpretation of the problem. The division into first putting a ball into every cell (to ensure each has at least one) and *then* dealing with "the rest" typically leads to overcounting.

Comment: well, I asked this my teacher intuitionally, and it took him 3 minutes to answer me. I believe he's right. I'm just a lil confused over $C(n,k)$, but it makes sense.

Comment: My interpretation is that this is the same as the following problem. We have $k$ different books and $n$ different bookshelves, and want to distribute the books between bookshelves, with at least one book per bookshelf and where order matters. As to formulas, my suggestion, once we agree on the interpretation of the problem, is to test formulas by counting explicitly for some quite small $k$ and $n$.  I note that at least we agree on the relationship between bonus question and first question.

Comment: I see, and what if there's no significance to the order?

Comment: If there is no significance of the order in the cells? The problem in the OP explicitly says order in the cells is significant. The problem then becomes more complicated. We can use Inclusion/Exclusion. The answer will involve Stirling numbers of the second kind (for details please see Wikipedia).

Comment: I see, then he answered me that answer when there's significance then.

Comment: I'll check later and update you about my answer.