# combinatorics - distinct objects into identical cells - when order matter

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, balls-in-bins

I got the following question:
how many options we have to divide N distinct objects into M identical cells when the order matter?

to be honest, Im a bit baffeld about how "order" matter effect the question, I believe its the first time I got a combinatoric question where there was importance to the order

I read a bit about dividing distinct objects into identical cells ( we didnt learn in class stirling number), and Im not sure how I should think about adjusting to the fact order matter

I found this:
[How many options do we have to divide $k$ balls to $n$ cells (2 conditions)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571507/how-many-options-do-we-have-to-divide-k-balls-to-n-cells-2-conditions)

where he kind of talk about the same question (the bouns) but I cant understand how he figured out the equation

Comment: André Nicolas's answer is using the [stars and bars approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: It is indeed completly unclear what the word "order" should mean in the context... May it be the order of items in the cell?

Comment: did my answer help you ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , your question and the question in given link are different from each other.Your question is asking for distinct object in $\color{blue}{\text{identical}}$ boxes where the orders of objects in each boxes matters , but the question in given link is asking for distinct object in $\color{blue}{\text{distinct}}$ boxes where the orders of objects in each boxes matters.

As far as i understood , you are not much familiar with combinatorics (because you say that you do not know Stirling Numbers), but your question requires alittle bit being familiar with combinatorics. I am putting here two links that solve your original question , i hope those can help you when you learn much things about combinatorics :

- *[First Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4256025/arranging-books-in-bookshelves-with-the-capacity-of-each-shelf-given)*
- *[Second Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329433/line-up-objects-in-each-box-after-using-stirling-number-of-second-kind)*

When we comes to the solution in given link , i think you must have heard about combination with repetition before. Think the question firstly as if it is a problem about distributing identical objects into distinct boxes.It is one of the classical problem of stars and bars method. After you find the solution , convert the identical object into distinct. You can make this convertion by putting an distinct object into (or over) each of the identical objects , and this process can be done by $k!$ ways.